# about shared_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr

Just want to clarify regarding shared_ptr

```
int main(){
   typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<Foo> _foo;

   _foo obja(new Foo());
   Foo *objb = obja.get(); 

   // delete objb; //deleting objb will throw double free or corruption
   return 0;
}
```

In the code above, is there a memory leak if *objb* is not deleted or freed? In the end, *obja* will go out of scope and will free itself. Since *objb* and *obja* are pointing in the same instance does that mean there's no need in freeing *objb*?

Is the above the same as this:

```
Foo *obja = new Foo();
Foo *objb;

objb = obja;
delete obja;
```

Comment: `-1` This code doesn't compile. Show some effort.

Comment: `shared_ptr` would be pretty damn useless if that code leaked. It's not designed by idiots. Also, doesn't the fact that deleting the pointer yourself causing a double delete give you a clue that the `shared_ptr` is doing it too?

Comment: Looks like either `_foo` should `_pff` or vice versa.

Comment: Fixed that. But @mak, please make sure that the code compiles the next time. A nice quick checking tool to fiddle around is [ideone.com](http://ideone.com).

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely Well sorry, I'm new to c/c++ and I'm not as smart as you are. I asked this hoping some humble expert explain things so it'll be clear to me. I didn't say shared_ptr is useless and is designed by idiots.

Comment: Sorry if the code didn't compile, I was already sleepy when I post this. I changed the names to make it shorter and made a mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the code above, is there a memory leak if objb is not deleted or freed?

**No.** The `Foo` object is owned by the `obja` shared pointer. By doing `.get()`, you retrieve a "dumb", observing pointer that does not have any influence on the lifetime of the pointed object. You just have to be careful not to dereference it after the pointed object has ceased to exist, or you will get Undefined Behavior.

> Since objb and obja are pointing in the same instance does that mean there's no need in freeing objb?

There is no need of freing `objb` because when `obja` goes out of scope, its destructor will `delete` the owned object. If you did `delete objb`, you would get Undefined Behavior by trying to delete an object twice.

> Is the above the same as this:

I guess one could say so, yes.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no leak. Raw pointers do not have any ownership semantics, and neither does `get`ting a raw pointer from a `shared_ptr` increase the reference count.

When the shared pointer goes out of scope in your example, the object pointed to is destroyed. As you have noticed already, manually deleting it consequently leads to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, no leak.  `obja` still owns the memory, and it is released when `obja` is destroyed at scope exit.  Getting the pointer isn't equivalent to releasing its ownership (q.v. `release()`).  So you're getting a weak (non-owning) pointer via `get()`, which is valid as long as the actual owner exists, but is a dangling pointer if the raw pointer outlives the owning `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

I think most answers above shows they do not understand where your confusion is.
So pointer in C and C++ is just an address of memory. When you "copy" one raw pointer to another you make them both point to the same address:

```
int *ptr1 = new int(); // points to memory at address lets say 1234;
int *ptr2 = ptr1; // now also points to 1234
*ptr1 = 10; // modify int where ptr1 points to
std::cout << *ptr2 << std""endl; // print 10 as ptr2 points to the same place as ptr1
delete ptr1; // I do not need memory at address 1234 anymore
delete ptr2; // I do not need memory at address 1234 again, error double deletion
```

You can look at pointers as numbers, when you assign one pointer to another you just copy that number, nothing happens to the memory at that address.